# MVC Razor, Javascript preload order of operations and feasibility

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a question regarding an order of operations and to get some feedback on feasibility.
This involves MVC Razor, Javascript and the HTML preload property.

I have a partial view that runs some Javascript.  It requires an external JS library to run but I don't want it to run on every page to save load times.

I know I can use MVC "Sections" to have blocks of code render within sections of a page by using the RenderSection function.  However, I have a partial view that is part of many templates.

So the structure of my template system (and this is because this is an off the shelf product), that the View structure is as below.

Root.cshtml (is the main layout wrapper)

< Root.Head.cshtml > (Partial view contained within Root.cshtml that has the HTML Head markup)

THEN,
OneColumn.cshtml, TwoColumn.cshtml (Inherit Root.cshtml as their "master" template)

THEN
ProductTemplate1.cshtml,ProductTemplate1.cshtml,ProductTemplate1.cshtml,ProductTemplate1.cshtml (these inherit EITHER "OneColumn" or "TwoColumn" as their "master" template).

THEN each of those "Product" templates can have a partial view of "Calendar.cshtml".

The 'Calendar.cshtml' is the one that requires the external JS library to run some of its functions.  I would like to have the external JS library only load if the Calendar.cshtml partial is included in a product template, BUT I want the library to not end up in the body of the HTML layout but instead, like any good formatted HTML, either in the HTML Head OR just before the closing tag of the HTML body.

Since the Calendar.cshtml file 'lives' in the Product template, the product template is actually already two levels deep in its inheritance of layouts.

My thought would be to put in the Calendar.cshtml file this code, BUT I don't know if it would load fast enough to allow the code that calls the external JS file to actually run.
Hence my question about the 'preload' property.

This is what I am thinking of putting in the 'calendar.cshtml' file.

```
  function loadJQUERYUI(){
  var importJQUERYUI= document.createElement('script');
  importJQUERYUI.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js';
  importJQUERYUI.async = 'true';
  importJQUERYUI.rel= 'preload';
 document.head.appendChild(importJQUERYUI);
 }
 loadJQUERYUI();

 <!--Code called in the Calendar.csthml partial-->
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

The thing is, would jQuery UI even load before the `.datepicker()` function fires?

I had looked at wrapping the `$('#datepicker').datepicker();` call in a timeout so it gives the external script time to load, but I don't know how long an external responding server will take to respond to the request.  That is super hacky, and don't really want to do that.
I tested it without a timeout and the `$('#datepicker').datepicker();` function fired before the call to the jQuery UI library loaded.  I tried it with a 1 second timeout and the datepicker loaded, but that is not ideal, because I don't know when the external library will respond in what timeframe.

If I were to use the MVC Razor "RenderSection", I have done it where it each section calls a sub section all the way down the line four levels deep, but since I have multiple templates that require this, isolating it so the Calendar.cshtml partial injects the external jQueryUI library is desired without having to next "RenderSections" all throughout my templates.

Is there another way?

Comment: Hmmmm, I wonder if there's a better / modern version of this https://bitbucket.org/forloop/forloop-htmlhelpers/wiki/Home ?

Comment: How about this? https://www.devready.co.uk/post/scripts-section-in-asp-net-core-partial-view